# Can i delete and erase the list of pointers like below

Tags: c++, list, pointers, iterator

This is the code from my program

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <list>

    int main()
    {
        std::list<int *> list;
       //populating the list with some pointers
        for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
        {
            int *p = new int(i);
            list.push_back(p);
        }
        //want to delete and erase the contents of the above list
        for(std::list<int *>::iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); iter++)
        {
           delete(*iter);
           list.erase(--iter);
        }  
        // trying to print the list contents
        for(std::list<int *>::iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); iter++)
        {
           std::cout<<*iter<<std::endl;
        }

    }
```

Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

It's a really bad idea to modify the list while you are iterating over it.

Also, each time through the list, you decrement `iter` and then increment it in the for statement - so it never moves.

I think what you need to do, is go over the loop deleting the pointers, and then just clear the whole list.

```
    for (const auto p: list)
        delete p;
    p.clear();
```

Even better, make the list be a list of unique_ptrs, and it's even easier:

```
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> list;
    //populating the list with some pointers
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
    {
        list.push_back( std::make_unique( i ) );
    }
    //want to delete and erase the contents of the above list
    list.clear();  // unique_ptr destructor will delete the memory.
```

Remember the mantra: Never write a naked new if you can avoid it.

Comment: It's also an extremely bad idea to modify the iterator.

Comment: Bit hard to progress through the loop unless you do modify it!

Comment: What I mean is, it is an extremely bad idea to manipulate the iterator itself, much as it is a super bad idea to manipulate the thing that you are iterating over (like deleting elements.)  Much better to operate on a copy.

Comment: Yeah!  Sorry, I knew what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your method is not only wrong but also terrible !!! It's because you are deleting the objects in the list & then using `std::cout` to print them which causes UB. Secondly you are using `erase` on the iterators which traversing them. Once you erase an iterator you are invalidating it & the references to it. So using `invalid iterators` again causes UB.

Next you needn't delete each element you are holding in the container. Containers work on the `RAII principle` & hence will free their resources automatically. So your erase code reduces to :-

```
for (auto itr = l.begin(); itr!=l.end(); ++itr)
    {
        delete  *itr;
    }
```

You need to be very careful when using iterators in C++ because no matter how useful they are, they aren't that easy to use for a beginner. But as you get to know them, you will find the comfort of using them & may like them too !

Comment: Actually, there's nothing wrong with the final loop.  It should print nothing (because the list is empty) - if the earlier code worked as intended.  It's the earlier code which is broken.

Comment: I think the point is that he want's to throw away the contents of the list *without relying on the destructor*.  So you need a list.clear() after your loop.

Comment: No @MartinBonner printing the deleted elements is a UB. It doesn't print anything in your system, it may break out in another, which means u cant comment how it will behave.

Plus the `clear` function isn't required, the destructor of `std::list` will take care of evrything, so y write an extra line & waste your time as well as runtime

Comment: Printing the deleted elements is UB of course.  My point is that if you have successfully erased the elements, then the loop will do nothing (because the list is empty), so you won't access the deleted elements - so no UB.  The point about the clear is that I am assuming this is a simple example, and there is supposed to be another huge chunk of code after the clear and before the destructor (for example the printing loop), which reuses the "list" variable (but obviously not the elements we have just deleted).

Comment: If list.clear() is the last use of list before it is destroyed, then yes, it is entirely superfluous.

Comment: right after u use `clear` only then it will do nothing